# HTML table rowspan or colspan issue?

Tags: html, html-table

We need to design a webpage layout. Using table we can divide layout into six zones (cells) as shown below:

ZONE 1  ZONE 2  ZONE 3

ZONE 4  ZONE 5  ZONE 6

Now, it is possible to merge ZONE 2, ZONE 5 and ZONE 6?
We need to use DIV?

Answer (score 2):

See: [Why tables for layout is stupid](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)

Use [CSS](http://www.subcide.com/articles/creating-a-css-layout-from-scratch/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am also thinking the same that div is the only solution. Just need to confirm as shifting from table to div is not easy. It will be very helpful if you can specify more resources for "crash course in Div based layouts". Thanks again.

Comment: @Malik - it'll be worth your while learning the CSS box model (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). Actually, take a look at all the CSS stuff at w3 schools - it's a great site (http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) - good luck!

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt response and resources. As you know that developers always face "THE RIGID DEADLINES". Anything more precise like the first resource will help a lot and may be i am able to have some sleep :(.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100%, but it sounds like a job for CSS. Why do you want tables?

(Is it crucial that Zone 1 & Zone 3 have equal height?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Zone 1 and Zone 3 have different widths and heights. We can control them using table but we are unable to merger ZONE 2, ZONE 5 and ZONE 6. Any help?

Comment: You will need to use floats: one div to float: left for Zone 1 & 4, one div for float: none for Zone 2, 5 & 6 and one div for float: right for Zone 3. The first to should not have any padding, margin etc, and have position: relative. In the first div (float: left) add two divs, no margin, no padding. 50% height. Add the three first divs in a container-div. I think it will work

Comment: Thanks again. Let me try. Will get back to you.

Comment: @Onkelborg: You should move your comment into your answer. It will be more useful. It's not really a comment - it's a good answer!